# Using VisualVM on JBoss application server

Tags: java, performance, jboss, visualvm, jvisualvm

I am trying to debug some memory leaks in my applications on JBoss 7. So I downloaded VisualVM, connected to running JBoss instance on localhost (which already took 5 minutes which si strange). BUT, I don't have the Perform GC option in Monitor section (button is disabled) and the Thread tab is missing completely. It is also the same for other Java applications like NetBeans, only with exception of the VisualVM itself.

I also tried jVisual and it can't event connect to my JBoss server. I've read that this can be caused by some user accounts issues (you can't run VisualVM as root) but I am running all these aplications under my personal account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem has been solved, you need to put `visualvm.sh` into `JBOSS_HOME/bin` and run VisualVM from there. [Here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/196428) you can find how to get this file. Then you need to connect through JMX with query like `service:jmx:remoting-jmx://{host_name}:{port}` (so in my case localhost:9999). That worked for me.